# jquery append() and container size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to append a string to a div using Jquery `.append()` method however the appended text does not fit the size of the box.

I've attached a fiddle showing the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JvYRM/25/

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
var tempS = '';
Object.keys(person).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, person[key]);
     tempS += key+'&'+person[key];
    $('.box').append(key+'&'+person[key]+'<br>');

});

 $('.box2').append(tempS);
```

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. In your example, the working string has spaces in it whereas the code generated string doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS' `word-break` property for the `.box2` element:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JvYRM/31/).

Incidentally, in your HTML, note that `&` should be encoded as `&amp;`, as it's the first character of HTML character-entities.

Reference:

- [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

Answer (score 1):

You need whitespace after each element if you want the possibility of a line break:

```
tempS += key+'&'+person[key] + " ";
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JvYRM/32/

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to wrap text without white space.  I've tested this solution and it seems to work.

Add this class to css:

```
.wordwrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

And update your div to include this class `<div class="box2 wordwrap"></div>`